# when is the `:` (colon) in necessary in ssreflect/Coq?

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I am trying to understand the exact meaning of the `:` (colon) in Coq/ssreflect proofs in terms of non-ssreflect Coq.

I read that it has something to do with moving things to the goal (like generalize??) and is the opposite of `=>`, which move things to the hypotheses. However, I often find it confusing because proofs work either way with or without the `:`. Below is an example from a tutorial:

```
Lemma tmirror_leaf2 t : tmirror (tmirror t) = Leaf -> t = Leaf.
Proof.
move=> e.
by apply: (tmirror_leaf (tmirror_leaf e)).
Qed.
```

where,

```
tmirror_leaf
     : forall t, tmirror t = Leaf -> t = Leaf
```

is a lemma that says if the mirror of a tree is a leaf, then the tree is a leaf.

I don't understand why we need the `:` here and not merely do the Coq `apply`. In fact, if I remove the `:`, it works just fine. Why does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer while reading the SSReflect documentation. Essentially, ssr has redefined tactics like `apply` such that it operates on the first variable of the goal instead of something in the context. That's why the `:` is used in `apply: XX.` in the ssr way (which is equivalent to `move: XX; apply.`), and it also works if `:` is omitted as that is the traditional Coq way.

Quoting the documentation:

> Furthermore, SSReflect redefines the basic Coq tactics case, elim, and
>   apply so that they can take better advantage of ':' and '=>'. These
>   Coq tactics require an argument from the context but operate on the
>   goal. Their SSReflect counterparts use the first variable or constant
>   of the goal instead, so they are "purely deductive":
>
> they do not use or change the proof context. There is no loss since
>   `:' can readily be used to supply the required variable.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, `apply: H1 ... Hn` is to all effects equivalent to `move: H1 .. Hn; apply`. A more interesting use of apply is `apply/H` and its variations, which can interpret views.